# Check for request.Get variable in django template when '?' is encoded

Tags: django, google-chrome, url, urlencode

When the url is www.example.com/abc/?q=xyz, we get the value of q in the template by putting {{request.GET.q}}. It works fine normally but in my case, the browser is encoding '?' in url to '%3F' (the url looks like: www.example.com/abc/%3Fq=xyz) and now {{request.GET.q}} gives nothing.

What is the solution.

Also, the url shows '?' only but when i click on it the url bar encodes it. The problem is only in chrome.

Comment: can you add you urls and views???... i'd tried make a request with '%3F' and I get a 404...

Comment: for your ease: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/company/signup/%3Fl=slug' is th url, where it should have been 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/company/signup/?l=slug' and both work the same. just the template cannot read the former